# Trying to connect NXT to C# using bluetooth

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, nxt

I am trying to receive a message from my LEGO NXT Robot in C# using serial ports, but this does not seem to work. I have connected the NXT on COM7 (Serial Port (SPP) Dev A). Then, I have tried the following options to allow the communication.

- I have used the code to wait for input from the port (*Read Data from port*-section in http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx) using baudRate = 57600. This console appliacation produces no results.
- I have tried using the code specific to this application from this project (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18857/Communicating-with-LEGO-NXT-via-Bluetooth-in-C), which works only by asking questions and waiting for replies. This however is not what I want, but still does not work (probably due to Hint 1 as mentioned by the author the bluetooth drivers must be from microsoft, which I am not sure how to do.

On the nxt, I have loaded a simple application that just initiates a connect with the PC (on 1) and then sends a number through connection 1.

Could you please tell me how to create a program in visual C# that will be capable of receiving messages from the nxt robot? It is crucial for the application to run on visual C# since the program managing the data must process them at real time and produce the output.